Red/blue colouring of $K_\alpha$ with no red $K_\alpha$ or blue $K_3$ for $\alpha=\omega^3$
This claims that the complete graph $K_\alpha$ for $\alpha = \omega^3$ can be red/blue coloured such that there is no red $K_\alpha$ and no blue $K_3$. It gives a reference to Specker, Ernst, Teilmengen von Mengen mit Relationen. However i do not speak german. Is there a reference translating this construction into english?

Consider an edge $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ where $\alpha\lt\beta\lt\omega^3$. Write $\alpha=\omega^2a_1+\omega a_2+a_3$ and $\beta=\omega^2b_1+\omega b_2+b_3$ where $a_i,b_i\lt\omega$. Colour the edge $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ blue if $a_1\lt a_2\lt b_1\lt a_3\lt b_2\lt b_3$, red otherwise. Then there is no red $K_{\omega^3}$ and no blue $K_3$.
This construction easily generalizes to $\omega^n$ where $3\le n\lt\omega$.
Here is an English-language reference for Specker's construction: Neil H. Williams, Combinatorial Set Theory, North-Holland, 1977. See Lemma 7.2.4 on p. 159.

I meant $\omega^3$ sorry, it was a typo. I know how to get a counterexample for $\omega^n$ where $3\leq n< \omega$ from one for $\omega^3$ using injective pins, so i'd like to know how to construct a counterexample for $\omega^3$.
